# Simple popover not working - Uncaught reference $ is not definted

Tags: jquery, popover, bootstrap-popover

Why is this code not working? It's a simple popover script. In the chrome inspector, I get error on this line `$(window).load(function () {`

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPopover" title="Ehioze" data-content="<img class='img-responsive' src'/images/1.png'>" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover">
      Ehioze
  </button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $("#popover").popover('show');
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't included jquery.js in the page. `popover()` isn't a standard jquery method either, so ensure you've included whatever library which contains it too.